# return res.status(401).json({ msg: "Auth Failed" });

Tags: node.js, express, mern

I am writing a middleware to verify jwt token. But I am getting an error as "can not read status of undefined"

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const keys = require('../config/keys')

const isLoogedIn = (req, res, next) => {
     try{
          const authToken = req.headers.authorization
          const decoded = jwt.verify(authToken, keys.JWT_KEY)
          req.userData = decoded
          return next()
     } catch(error){
          return res.status(401).json({msg: "Auth Failed"})
     }
     
}
```

I should verify the token, if the token is valid then next(). If there is an error then sending msg with status code 401.

Comment: how are you calling `isLoogedIn`? Please post that in the question.

Comment: Are you passing `isLoggedIn` into `app.use(isLoggedIn)` to add it to your middleware stack? 

The error suggests not, as it is trying to read the `status` method of the `res` object, but if it's not part of the middleware stack the `res` object is not being defined.

Comment: Just saw that I forgot about this. So, that issue was with a syntax error while calling it. Silly mistake.